# How to remove strings portion in variable and write those values back to variable in one-liner

Tags: powershell

i have problem like this, let's say i have an array like this:

```
$PSnames ='Win10-PS' , 'Server-PS', 'Client-PS'
```

Now I want to remove the “-PS” portion of each name in the $PSnames variable AND write those values back to the variable but this must be a one-liner. I tried using the foreach-object cmdlet with the pipeline, but the S in Server-PS is also lost.

```
$PSnames
Win10-PS
Client-PS
Server-PS



$PSnames | ForEach-Object {$_.Trim("-PS")}

Win10
Client
erver
```

I don't know how to handle and re-insert -PS portion in one-liner.

Could anyone give me an explanation as well as the solution? Thanks and i'm appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The `.Trim()` method does not work as you probably think it does. ;-) I'd recommend using the `-replace` operator like this:

```
$PSnames ='Win10-PS' , 'Server-PS', 'Client-PS'
$PSnames = $PSnames -replace '-PS'
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, but another question,how can we put those replaced value back to variable , i mean replace -PS and then immediately add it to each object in array  in one-liner.

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm unsure if I got what you mean. If you want  to write the output back to the original array you use it just like I suggested it in my ocde?!  Arrays in PowerShell are immutable. You can only overwrite them with a new version of the array with new elements.

Comment: @zett42 Ui ... I wasn't aware of that. Changed the code suggestion to this. Thank you very much.